# Is it possible to build salesforce apex kind of framework using golang plugin?

Tags: go, multi-tenant, apex

Need to run golang code run dynamically. I have golang function as a string.   Dynamically creating a new golang file and using exec command to run that go file won't be faster and also not a correct approach.

So I am trying to write my function as a plugin. But where to store that function? In multi-tenancy app we cannot store all plugin's in app container. Can anyone explain with example?

I referred https://appliedgo.net/plugins/

Comment: That link appears to predate the inclusion of the https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/ package in the standard library. You can now use compiled Go plugins in-process on Linux and MacOS.

Comment: Yes. But I need to have  plugins for each user in the database. So where to store the plugin? How load and unload the plugin to each request?

Comment: If you're going to handle more than one request at a time, you wouldn't want to load and unload the plugins for each request; not only would that be incredibly slow, it would also cause all sorts of issues because plugins are global, there's no way to have a request-scoped plugin. You'll want to carefully consider your design and how this would actually work in practice before you commit to an architecture and implementation.

Comment: Any other way to achieve this? Any script like lua will work?

Comment: There are probably many ways to achieve whatever you're trying to accomplish (though the question is pretty light on details). However, *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.